# Please explain how this high-side switch circuit works

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Please help me to understand this high-side switch circuit:

[image]

**MCU_OUT** is from an ESP32 module.

**Load** is a 12 V buzzer to ground.

I would like to understand how it works.

How will T1 turn on Q1? How will Q1 will turn on the (buzzer) load?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about this circuit? Do you know how transistors or MOSFETs work?

Comment: It's quite badly drawn but, if it were redrawn would it help you?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/667030/334997 In this answer I explained a very similar circuit, just replacing the BJT with a mosfet.

Comment: Q1 should be pMOS not nMOS.

Comment: *the buzzer 12 V.*  If the buzzer is connected to 12V, it will not work.  Ground maybe.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: "the buzzer 12V" appears to be a specification of the buzzer's working voltage, and not a statement on how the other terminal is connected.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get it, but it would be better if the OP posted the full schematic.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a couple circuits that will actually work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0XUfL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The one on the left is a high-side switch, necessary if you want one side of the load to be grounded. The two resistors limit the gate voltage to 1/2 of the 12V source when on, since the AO34xx parts have a +/-12 Vgs absolute maximum. A similar P-channel MOSFET is substituted for the N-channel type.
When the BC847 is off, R2 pulls the gate voltage up to the source so the MOSFET is off. When the BC847 is on (base current is flowing) then R2/R3 form a voltage divider putting -6V on the gate relative to the source, turning it on.

The one on the right is simpler and should be used if the load does not need to be grounded on one side.

If the buzzer is electromechanical you may need a diode across it to protect the MOSFET.

Neither circuit is suitable for an automotive 12V source without additional protection from transients.

Answer (score 4):

That is a incorrect attempt at making a High-side switch circuit, twisted in an unnatural pose and using the wrong polarity MOSFET, which causes the buzzer to buzz constantly.

T1 is a common emitter NPN BJT circuit that converts from a control signal referenced to ground to one referenced to the 12 V supply. In so doing, it also inverts the polarity.

Q1 *should be* a common source P-channel MOSFET circuit that converts the control signal referenced to a power switch referenced to ground. However, it uses an N-channel MOSFET instead. The result is that its intrinsic diode is permanently forward-biased. In other words, it acts as an permanently turned-on switch.

Therefore, the buzzer buzzes constantly.

To fix this circuit, replace the MOSFET with a P-channel MOSFET, such as the AO3401.